# Patterns with multi-terms entries in the IN attribute

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am extending a spaCy model using rules. While looking through the documentation, I noticed the [`IN` attribute](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#adding-patterns-attributes-extended), which is used to map patterns to a dictionary of properties. This is great however it only works on single tokens.

For example, this pattern: `{"label":"EXAMPLE","pattern":[{"LOWER": {"IN": ["such as", "like", "for example"]}}]}` will only work with the term `like` but not the others.

What is the best way to achieve the same result for multi-terms attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how complicated the intended patterns are, but the `PhraseMatcher` can handle similar cases as above using the attribute `LOWER`:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher

nlp = spacy.blank("en")
pmatcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab, attr="LOWER")
phrases = ["such as", "like", "for example"]
pmatcher.add("EXAMPLE", [nlp(x) for x in phrases])
assert pmatcher(nlp("Things Such As Books")) == [(15373972490796046842, 1, 3)]
```

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of the `PhraseMatcher` but I don't think you can use the `PhraseMatcher` as part of a pattern.

Comment: I guess I could use the `PhraseMatcher` to label an entity and then use that entity as part of a pattern... I'll try that.

Comment: While trying this, I encountered a different issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62019695/patterns-with-ent-type-from-manually-labelled-span-not-working