# Patterns with ENT_TYPE from manually labelled Span not working

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

As an alternative to accomplishing this: [Patterns with multi-terms entries in the IN attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61975312/patterns-with-multi-terms-entries-in-the-in-attribute/62000246#62000246)

I wrote the following code to match phrases, label them, and then use them in `EntityRuler` patterns:

```py
# %%
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler
from spacy.tokens import Span

class PhraseRuler(object):
    name = 'phrase_ruler'

    def __init__(self, nlp, terms, label):
        patterns = [nlp(term) for term in terms]
        self.matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
        self.matcher.add(label, None, *patterns)

    def __call__(self, doc):
        matches = self.matcher(doc)
        spans = []
        for label, start, end in matches:
            span = Span(doc, start, end, label=label)
            spans.append(span)
        doc.ents = spans
        return doc

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")

entity_matcher = PhraseRuler(nlp, ["Best Wishes", "Warm Welcome"], "GREETING")
nlp.add_pipe(entity_matcher, before="ner")


ruler = EntityRuler(nlp)
patterns = [{"label": "SUPER_GREETING", "pattern": [{"LOWER": "super"}, {"ENT_TYPE": "GREETING"}]}]
ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
#ruler.to_disk("./data/patterns.jsonl")
nlp.add_pipe(ruler)

print(nlp.pipe_names) 

doc = nlp("Mary said Best Wishes and I said super Warm Welcome.")
print(doc.to_json())
```

Unfortunately this does not work as it does not return my `SUPER_GREETING`:

```
'ents': [
   {'start': 0, 'end': 4, 'label': 'PERSON'}, 
   {'start': 10, 'end': 21, 'label': 'GREETING'}, 
   {'start': 39, 'end': 51, 'label': 'GREETING'}
]
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea, but the problem here is an intrinsic design choice in spaCy that any token can only be part of one named entity. So you can't have "Warm Welcome" being both a "GREETING" as well as part of a "SUPER_GREETING".

One way you could work around this is by using [custom extensions](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components-attributes). For instance, one solution would be to store the GREETING bit on the token level:

```
Token.set_extension("mylabel", default="")
```

And then we adjust the `PhraseRuler.__call__` so that it doesn't write to `doc.ents` but instead does this:

```
for token in span:
    token._.mylabel = "MY_GREETING"
```

Now, we can rewrite the SUPER_GREETING pattern to:

```
patterns = [{"label": "SUPER_GREETING", "pattern": [{"LOWER": "super"}, {"_": {"mylabel": "MY_GREETING"}, "OP": "+"}]}]
```

which will match "super" followed by one or more "MY_GREETING" tokens. It will match greedily and output "super Warm Welcome" as hit.

Here's the resulting code snippet, starting from your code and making the adjustements as described:

```
    Token.set_extension("mylabel", default="")

    class PhraseRuler(object):
        name = 'phrase_ruler'

        def __init__(self, nlp, terms, label):
            patterns = [nlp(term) for term in terms]
            self.matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
            self.matcher.add(label, None, *patterns)

        def __call__(self, doc):
            matches = self.matcher(doc)
            for label, start, end in matches:
                span = Span(doc, start, end, label=label)
                for token in span:
                    token._.mylabel = "MY_GREETING"
            return doc

    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")

    entity_matcher = PhraseRuler(nlp, ["Best Wishes", "Warm Welcome"], "GREETING")
    nlp.add_pipe(entity_matcher, name="entity_matcher", before="ner")

    ruler = EntityRuler(nlp)
    patterns = [{"label": "SUPER_GREETING", "pattern": [{"LOWER": "super"}, {"_": {"mylabel": "MY_GREETING"}, "OP": "+"}]}]
    ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
    nlp.add_pipe(ruler, after="entity_matcher")

    print(nlp.pipe_names)

    doc = nlp("Mary said Best Wishes and I said super Warm Welcome.")
    print("TOKENS:")
    for token in doc:
        print(token.text, token._.mylabel)
    print()

    print("ENTITIES:")
    for ent in doc.ents:
        print(ent.text, ent.label_)
```

Which outputs

```
TOKENS:
Mary 
said 
Best MY_GREETING
Wishes MY_GREETING
and 
I 
said 
super 
Warm MY_GREETING
Welcome MY_GREETING
. 

ENTITIES:
Mary PERSON
super Warm Welcome SUPER_GREETING
```

This may not be exactly what you need/want - but I hope it helps you move forward with an alternative solution for your specific use-case. If you do want the normal "GREETING" spans in the final `doc.ents`, maybe you can reassemble them in post-processing, after the `EntityRuler` has run, e.g. by moving the custom attributes to `doc.ents` if they don't overlap, or by keeping a cache of the `spans` somewhere.

Comment: Thank you Sophie, I will try it and mark it as an answer very soon :-)

Comment: Your answer is valid and pointed me in the right direction (esp. `intrinsic design choice in spaCy that any token can only be part of one named entity`). Instead of using your solution however, I just used `overwrite_ents` ie. `ruler = EntityRuler(nlp, overwrite_ents=True)`. I am going to mark your answer as the answer anyhow :-) Thanks again

Comment: Sure, you could do that too if you don't mind the "GREETING" annotations being lost ;-) Happy to hear you found a solution and thanks for posting your alternative!

Comment: Actually I just found an issue with my solution... It is not greedy, so it will only pick up the first token of the previous entity ie. `super Warm` instead of `super Warm Welcome` :-(